# How to add selected items from checkboxlist to string array?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

```
public string[] selected()
{

    string[] selecteditems = new string[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < chbindustry.Items.Count-1; i++)
    {
        if (chbindustry.Items[i].Selected)
        {

            selecteditems[i] = chbindustry.Items[i].Text.ToString();


            //string Va = string.Empty;
            //Va = chbindustry.Items[i].Text.ToString();
           // selecteditems[i] = Va;
        }

    }
    return selecteditems;
}
```

In this code I want to add checkboxlist selected items to string array "selecteditems[i]" here using "selecteditems[i]" I need to bind it in below code and show to only selected items

```
foreach (string s in subdirectoryEntries)
            {
                DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(s);
                for (int i = 1; i <= d.GetFiles().Length / 3; i++)
                {
                    selected();
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("ImgPaths", "'" + "BusinessCards/" + s.Remove(0, s.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1) + "/" + i + ".jpg'");
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("refs", "'" + "DesignBCs.aspx?img=BusinessCards/" + s.Remove(0, s.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1) + "/" + i + "&Side=2'");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

try with this.

```
public string[] selected()
{
    string strTemp = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < chbindustry.Items.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (chbindustry.Items[i].Selected)
        {
            strTemp += chbindustry.Items[i].Text.ToString() + ",";
        }
    }
    string[] selecteditems = strTemp.Split(','); 
    return selecteditems;
}
```

.........
.........
Edit 1:

```
string[] selecteditems = selected();
foreach (string s in subdirectoryEntries)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) && selecteditems.Contains(s)) //Folder is selected in ListItem
    {
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(s);
        for (int i = 1; i <= d.GetFiles().Length / 3; i++)
        {
            selected();
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("ImgPaths", "'" + "BusinessCards/" + s.Remove(0, s.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1) + "/" + i + ".jpg'");
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("refs", "'" + "DesignBCs.aspx?img=BusinessCards/" + s.Remove(0, s.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1) + "/" + i + "&Side=2'");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in below code it showing selected folder so how can i put in that code only selected items

Comment: in array its taking another blanck array??

Comment: I thought that your both code snippet in different methods. If you stored in to the another variable then you will get better performance. If you will write 'selected().Contains(s)', you will get performance issue.